# Creating Filters in OpenCV (C++)

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Me and my friends have recently started working with OpenCV to create webcam graphics in C++. After experimenting with facial tracking, and applying simple shapes to the screen for face detection, we want to see if we can use pre-made images to serve as visual filters to the camera (kind of like how SnapChat lets you put image graphics over your face).  We've asked on the OpenCV forums about this, but the only response we got was a link to how its done in Python, with no mention of C++. We know that it can be done in Python, but we can't find any way of implementing this in C++. Can anyone give us a hand? Is it even possible to do in C++?

Comment: You have a working implementation using the library you want, what else do you need? Just port it to C++.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. We can create simple shapes by raw-coding them into our implementation, but we can't figure out how to import pre-existing images and using them as face-filters. we can't find any mention of how to accomplish this in C++. We can't find anything in the c++ opencv library that lets us do this.

Comment: What does the Python code you refer to look like? The OpenCV Python API maps pretty much 1-1 to the C++ API, other than the way some of the data types are represented. Usually it's quite straightforward to port the code between the two languages.

Comment: well if you dont mind, here is the link to the code that imports a jpg file and uses it as an image filter.http://sublimerobots.com/2015/02/dancing-mustaches/